# Using a 100W External Power Pack to Run / Charge an Old 19.5v Laptop

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, battery-charging, adapter

I have just ordered the new Flash 2.0 battery pack. Specs [are here](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/flash-world-s-most-powerful-210w-usb-c-powerbank/x/24615495#/), but briefly:
100W USB-C Power Delivery 3.0 Output: 5V/3A, 9V/3A, 12V/3A, 15V/3A, 20V/5A (PPS)

I've also got an old HP Pavillion whose output from its AC adapter is 19.5v / 3.33A - 65W. It does not have a USB-C port.

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way I can use the external battery pack's USB-C to charge the laptop using off the shelf components. I've searched for converters and adapters, but nothing is looking promising. It seems like it should be doable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: google `USB PD triggers` ... you can buy a trigger module that is really small and it may fit inside the laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
The 20V, 5A spec is adequate to provide the required 19,5V, 3.33A.
But ...

The "easy " way is to use the adaptor offered as an option by the power pack's supplier.
They say

> Optional universal USB-C to laptop cable, means you can charge all major laptop brands with 1 patent-pending cable and an interchangeable adapter (HP, Asus, Dell, Alienware, Lenovo, Razer, Acer, Huawei, MSI, Samsung). This cable with 10 adapters will be available as an addon at the end of the campaign for $19.

---

Or, you can use one of the available after-market adaptors.
**This can work well, but may not**.

[This](https://www.zdnet.com/article/usb-c-power-for-laptops-is-still-complicated-and-heres-why/) April 2020 article discusses some of the possible problems.

> USB-C power for laptops is still complicated - and here's why
> The Infinity interchangeable magnetic cable supports USB-C Power Delivery up to 100W, but that doesn't mean you can just plug in and charge everything. ...

July 2020 article "Charging via USB-C for laptops: Here’s what you need to know"  [here](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/charging-via-usb-c/)

November 2019 Superuser related discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1506248/usb-c-to-laptop-charger)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer and links. Me HP laptop has a 4.5mm x 3.0mm tip and I found the adapter below which advertises a "Built-in a PD chip" but doesn't mention "trigger". Does PD imply trigger?

If not I guess I could buy adapter tips?


 https://www.amazon.com/CERRXIAN-Degree-Charging-Notebooks-4506-100w/dp/B08FQSK6GG/ref=sr_1_9?dchild=1&keywords=Usb-c%20to%20dc%2020v%204.5mm%20x%203.0mm&qid=1599389217&s=electronics&sr=1-9

Comment: Looks like this one will work and mentions trigger https://www.amazon.com/4-5x3-0mm-USB-C-Input-Laptop-4-53-0mm/dp/B07W6ZGRTD

Answer (score 1):

You basically need a usb-c trigger cable with that talks to the usb-c and emulates a 20V request. At that point you just need to verify two things: 1) that your laptop can handle 20V safely (with a 19.5 volt typical I'd imagine this will be just fine) and 2) make sure the connector is the right size and configuration. Keep in mind the center pin is usually the positive but not always, if your laptop needs the reverse of this make sure you get the right connector.

Here is a device on amazon that will solve your problem assuming the above concerns are considered:

[https://www.amazon.com/Cablecc-Emulator-Trigger-Charge-Laptop/dp/B07PBG4GY6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PBG4GY6)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer and links. Me HP laptop has a 4.5mm x 3.0mm tip and I found the adapter below which advertises a "Built-in a PD chip" but doesn't mention "trigger". Does PD imply trigger?

If not I guess I could buy adapter tips?


 https://www.amazon.com/CERRXIAN-Degree-Charging-Notebooks-4506-100w/dp/B08FQSK6GG/ref=sr_1_9?dchild=1&keywords=Usb-c%20to%20dc%2020v%204.5mm%20x%203.0mm&qid=1599389217&s=electronics&sr=1-9

Comment: No PD stands for Power Delivery. but thats ok, the word trigger isnt critical. the link you provided is roughly equivalent to the one I gave you. Please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: @mseifert oh sorry I didnt notice you had accepted a different answer. Its all good, I'm happy to hear more than one answer solved your problem.

Comment: Actually, I'm reviewing which answer helped the most. The other is more thorough, yours provided an actual link. I'm not sure if I would have found the links without your answer. As I said in my (deleted) comment, I wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: @mseifert It is indeed usually best to accept which answer you feel answers the question the best, and not just which one is first. With that said, I leave it up to you to make the judgement call.